# Detect if a user has accepted a Facebook app request from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-requests

Using the Facebook SDK in iOS, is it possible to detect from the iOS app, when a user has had their app request accepted by another user?

Looking at Candy Crush as an example: User A asks for a life, then User B accepts, how is it that User A is notified that User B sent them a life?

Comment: By another user? - not possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, nor should it be (for privacy reasons).

Comment: Hmm, so how do other games like Candy Crush accomplish this? For example User A asks for a life, then User B accepts, how is it that User A is notified that User B sent them a life?